# PHP PDO and COLLATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I fail to select some entries in a mysql database, comparing french strings with accentuated characters.

Datas samples below are oversimplified for more readability. And I try to be precise, so it's a bit long (sorry).

**Context**

In database, I have some strings like "année", "annee", "début", "debut", etc. The table and columns are charset utf8 with collate utf8_general_ci.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.30 and PHP 5.4.13 with PDO initializing with charset utf8 :

```
$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->base . ';charset=utf8', $this->user, $this->pass);
```

**In mysql console client**

If I SELECT without any collate precision, like

```
AND data = :data
```

with :data = "année". I will get lines with "année" AND "annee".

Then I SELECT with utf8_bin collate precision, like

```
AND data = :data COLLATE utf8_bin
```

with :data = "année", and I retrieve only lines with "année". COOL.

**With PHP PDO**

If I use same SQL in PHP script, with collate precision, I get this error message :

```
 COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

If I use `binary` collation, like

```
AND data = :data COLLATE `binary`
```

I get the error message

```
 COLLATION 'binary' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

**So, my questions are**

In PHP script

- "How to set explicitely the charset ?" (I believed I did that in PDO
  string initialization, but it seems to be wrong. "SET NAMES ..." does not work any better in this case)
- "How can I retrieve correct results with PDO when comparing with accentuated characters?"

**Precisions**

Here are more details (ask in comments).

*Extract from the "show create table"

```
CREATE TABLE `Request` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_id` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
....
`domain_version_corrective` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

*Two sample SELECT (from console, not with PHP / PDO):

```
SELECT domain_id, domain_version_corrective FROM Request WHERE client_id = 3661 AND domain_version_corrective = 'vèrçion 2.0' ;
```

which returns

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| domain_id | domain_version_corrective |
+-----------+---------------------------+
| FOOBAR    | vercion 2.0               |
| FOOBAR    | vèrcion 2.0               |
| FOOBAR    | verçion 2.0               |
| FOOBAR    | vèrçion 2.0               |
| FOOBAR    | vèrcion 2.0               |
+-----------+---------------------------+
```

And

```
SELECT domain_id, domain_version_corrective FROM Request WHERE client_id = 3661 AND domain_version_corrective = 'vèrçion 2.0' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

which returns

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| domain_id | domain_version_corrective |
+-----------+---------------------------+
| FOOBAR    | vèrçion 2.0               |
+-----------+---------------------------+
```

*The charsets :

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Plz provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the full `SELECT` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`. something is calling it `BINARY`, instead of `VARCHAR`.  Be sure to log in with the same user as the program.  It should not be "root".  Also, do you have `init_connect` in your  my.cnf?

Comment: @RickJames, I added the asked details on the question itself. I'm using same credentials in console and php script (not root). And there's empty string as init_connect variable. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: have you tried `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "set names utf8"` as the option for your connection in `PDO`?

Comment: @EhsanT, yes, but without success :(

Comment: so, how about adding this line: `$dbh->exec("set names utf8");` just right after opening your connection?

Comment: @EhsanT, please, re-read my (long) description, I already try that solution. Thanks for your time, anyway :)

Comment: Your two examples with `domain_version_corrective = 'vèrçion 2.0'` are "correct".  The `utf8_bin` version returns the one line that matches exactly.  The other strips accents before comparing and return those 6 lines.  The _collation_ controls case folding and accent stripping (`_ci`).  It is best to provide the collation in the table/column definition.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, they're "correct", if I run these queries in console. But I can't reproduce the same result with PHP/PDO, that's the point of this question. And I can't change the table/column definition :(

Comment: Your two errors from PHP PDO seem impossibly inconsistent.  One implies that `data` was `binary`, the other implies `utf8`.  We are missing something subtle.  Please show the whole PDO call with the `SELECT` for the two cases.

Comment: @RickJames, you're right (again ;) ), and I think it's the database schema which is inconsistent... The real sql is too long to copy/paste here (6 joins, lots of fields and conditions, ...). So I stop here. Many many thanks for your support !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I succeeded by wrapping the parameter with convert(), like so:

```sql
data = convert(:data using utf8) collate utf8_bin
```

It appears that PDO always tags string parameters with character set BINARY by PDO. It would be really nice to find out how to change this.

Also, I'm not sure if it's actually correct to convert the string to UTF8 like this, I suppose technically it could depend on how PHP represents the string internally.

Comment: I just tried this solution and got the wanted result !! Thanx joki